# .htaccess rule to remove index.php at the end of urls

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Hello guys can someone help me with a .htaccess rule to remove /index.php at the end of urls

example if someone try to access:

the-url-address.html/index.php

another-url-address.html/index.php

they should be redirected to:

the-url-address.html

another-url-address.html

removing the /index.php from the end of url

Answer (score 2):

You can use this rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
# set index.php as the default handler
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine On

# remove index.php from the end of URI
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)index\.php$ /$1 [L,R=302,NC,NE]
```

Comment: Using that it will redirect all urls ending with a /index.php to website homepagge, and i dont want that, i want them to be redirected to the url before /index.php part

Comment: Above will also redirect `http://site.com/dir/index.php` to `http://site.com/dir`

Comment: for me redirects everything which ends with /index.php to website homepage

Comment: If you provide just `http://site.com/index.php` it will be redirected to `http://site.com/` but if you enter: `http://site.com/somedir/index.php` then it will get redirected to: `http://site.com/somedir`

Comment: but if i provide http://site.com/some-url.html/index.php it will redirect to http://site.com/  and i want it to go  http://site.com/some-url.html

Comment: **That shouldn't happen as per these rules.** Try removing the slash before `$1` like `RewriteRule ^(.*?)index\.php$ $1 [L,R=302,NC,NE]`

Answer (score 1):

This was solved in my question, you need to add

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)index\.php$ /$1 [L,R=302,NC,NE]
```

Right under the RewriteEngine On call

example:

```
########## Begin - RewriteEngine enabled
RewriteEngine On
########## End - RewriteEngine enabled

########## remove index.php from the end of URI
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)index\.php$ /$1 [L,R=302,NC,NE]
##########
```