# .htaccess rule to remove index.php from the end of my urls

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, joomla

I have seen this asked before without an answer here: [.htaccess rule to remove index.php at the end of urls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19832638/htaccess-rule-to-remove-index-php-at-the-end-of-urls)

I'm having the same issue as the original poster. I have urls on my Joomla site that are showing up with index.php at the end. I want all urls ending with index.php to be redirected to the same page without the index.php at the end.

Example: **www.mysite.com/forum/index.php** should be redirected to **www.mysite.com/forum**

I have tried this code

```
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*?)index\.php$ /$1 [L,R=302,NC,NE]
```

But it redirects all url's with index.php at the end to my sites home page

Example **www.mysite.com/forum/index.php** ends up being redirected to **www.mysite.com**

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you post your full .htaccess in question

Comment: Then keep this rule just below `RewriteEngine On`

Comment: Perfect that was it, so it was the order of the calls, thanks!

Comment: How can I exclude a specific directory? This rule causes issues in the admin back end of the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule as your very first rule:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/admin/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)index\.php$ /$1 [L,R=302,NC,NE]
```

Comment: That does not work, it has the same results as before I added the rule right after RewriteEngine On it causes all pages that end in index.php to go to the site root and the admin backend to not be able to display index.php

Comment: This fixed the issue of non "admin" pages being redirected to the home page but it still breaks the admin part. During the login process to the admin back end it requires the index.php page to be displayed or you just loop and are not allowed to log in.

Comment: This won't affect anything that starts with `/admin/`

Comment: Unfortunately it does affect the url www.mysite.com/admin/index.php when I try to log in it redirects me to www.mysite.com/admin/

Comment: Ah sorry I had a typo. It is fixed now. Can you try updated rule?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68746/discussion-between-yaksushi-and-anubhava).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem but that code wasn't working for me, I used this one instead:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]
```